# Pick image doesn't work in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile

I was trying to implement a function in my project so that the user could choose the profile photo they wanted. However, pick image from gallery doesn't work. At the end, when I click on the ImageView that would open the gallery, the application “blinks” but does nothing.

```
package com.ete.smarthub;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class FormCadastro extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText signupUsername;
    EditText signupSenha;
    EditText signupEmail;
    TextView logincadastroText;
    Button signupButton;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference reference;
    FirebaseAuth fAuth;
    ImageView ImguserPhoto;
    static int PReqCode = 1 ;
    static int REQUESCODE = 1 ;
    Uri pickedImgUri ;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_form_cadastro);

        signupUsername = findViewById(R.id.signup_username);
        signupSenha = findViewById(R.id.signup_senha);
        signupEmail = findViewById(R.id.signup_email);
        logincadastroText = findViewById(R.id.logincadastroText);
        signupButton = findViewById(R.id.signup_button);
        ImguserPhoto = findViewById(R.id.regUserPhoto);

        ImguserPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 22) {
                    checkAndRequestForPermission ();
                }
                else{
                    openGallery();
                }
            }
        });

        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


        signupButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                reference = database.getReference("users");

                String Email = signupEmail.getText().toString();
                String Usuario = signupUsername.getText().toString();
                String Senha = signupSenha.getText().toString();

                HelperClass helperClass = new HelperClass(Email, Usuario, Senha);
                reference.child(Usuario).setValue(helperClass);

                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(Usuario)){
                    signupUsername.setError("Campo de Usuário vazio!");
                return;
                }

                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(Email)){
                    signupEmail.setError("Campo de Email vazio!!");
                    return;
                }
                if(Senha.length() < 6){
                    signupSenha.setError("Senha deve conter no mínimo 6 caracteres!");
                    return;

                }
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(Senha)){
                    signupSenha.setError("Campo de Senha vazio!");
                    return;
                }

                fAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(Email, Senha).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(FormCadastro.this, "Cadastro Realizado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(FormCadastro.this, FormLogin.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }else {
                            Toast.makeText(FormCadastro.this, "Erro!" + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        });


    logincadastroText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(FormCadastro.this, FormLogin.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    }

    private void openGallery() {
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, REQUESCODE);
    }

    private void checkAndRequestForPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(FormCadastro.this,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(FormCadastro.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                Toast.makeText(FormCadastro.this,"Aceite a permissão necessária", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(FormCadastro.this,
                                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                                    PReqCode);
            }

        }
        else
            openGallery();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUESCODE && data != null ){

            pickedImgUri = data.getData() ;
            ImguserPhoto.setImageURI(pickedImgUri);

        }
    }
}
```

**In fact, I have already granted permission in the Manifest file.**

There is a part of the text in the code that is cut and says:
**'startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int)' is deprecated**

The part where startActivity is cut off:
**startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, REQUESCODE);**

obs: only the -startActivityForResult-

Comment: Need more information. Manifest file permissions and TargetSdk version

Comment: From Api 33 READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE not work, you should use READ_MEDIA_IMAGES

Comment: `Pick image doesn't work in Android Studio` You mean: does not work in my Android app?

Comment: Please remove all permission code. You do not need any permission to use ACTION_GET_CONTENT. Remove all Firebase code as it is irrelevant. Also remove all imports. Remove all textviews and editviews stuff as all is irrelevant.

Comment: Please remove all code. Only openGallery() and onActivityResult() are relevant.

Comment: It works, thanks.